# Is it possible using C# generic

Tags: c#, generics

Here is the interface I need to define. I could not because generic type parameter in Parameters property does not exist. Is there a way to achieve this kind of interface definition in C#?

**UPDATED** 
I did not want to define interface like this: `ICriteria<T>`.

```
public interface ICriteria
{
    string Text { get; set; }
    IList<IParameter<T>> Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATED**

As more detail required why I would not want go that route. Here is more information about it.
 I have Parameter interface and implementaion like this

```
public interface IParameter<T>
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    T Value { get; set; }
}

public class Parameter<T> : IParameter<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

And the method consumes above implementation like this

```
public ICriteria BuildQuery()
    {
        ICriteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.Text = "dbo.Messages";

        var chatRoom = new Parameter<int>() { Name = "ChatRoomId", Value = _chatRoomId };
        var startDate = new Parameter<DateTime>() { Name = "StartDate", Value = _startDateTime };
        var endDate = new Parameter<DateTime>() { Name = "EndDate", Value = _endDateTime };

        //I want to add all parameters to criteria instance
        criteria.Parameters.Add(chatRoom);
        criteria.Parameters.Add(startDate);
        criteria.Parameters.Add(endDate);

        return criteria;
    }
```

The above method creates different type of parameters and try to add them to Parameters list in ICriteria interface. Hope it make sense.

Comment: Given that the sensible solution *is* to declare it as `ICriteria<T>`,  you need to give us more information about *why* you don't want to go down that route.

Comment: @JonSkeet updated the question with more details.

Comment: And how does the criteria *use* the parameters? See my answer - I suspect the last part would work fine for you. Basically you want a *non-generic* `IParameter` interface.

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought Criteria property implementation would be public IList<IParameter<T>> Parameters{get set code in here}. But it does not work that way. I think my question is wrong and should asked in different way. Let me try your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, you can't do that. But what you *could* do is this:

```
public interface IParameter
{
    // Any members which don't need T
}

public interface IParameter<T> : IParameter
{
    // Any members which do need to refer to T
}

public interface ICriteria
{
    string Text { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<IParameter> WeakParameters { get; }
}

public interface ICriteria<T> : ICriteria
{
    IList<IParameter<T>> StrongParameters { get; }
}
```

A typical implementation would make the `WeakParameters` call just return `StrongParameters` (assuming you're using C# 4 with generic covariance). Another option would be to make the strong form *hide* the weak form:

```
// Parameter types as before

public interface ICriteria
{
    string Text { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<IParameter> Parameters { get; }
}

public interface ICriteria<T> : ICriteria
{
    new IList<IParameter<T>> Parameters { get; }
}
```

Then anything which only had a reference of compile-time type `ICriteria` would get the "weak" sequence, whereas anything with a reference of compile-time type `ICriteria<T>` would get the "strong" list.

EDIT: This is all assuming that you want a single `T` for all parameters on a single `ICriteria` instance. If that's *not* the case, then you might want:

```
// Parameter types as before

public interface ICriteria
{
    string Text { get; set; }
    IList<IParameter> Parameters { get; }
}
```

You can *add* any kind of `IParameter<T>` to it, varying the `T` with each call, but when you're *reading* the parameters you don't have the information (at compile-time) about which parameter has which type (or indeed whether the parameter even implements the strongly-typed interface).

Comment: +1 Coming from a stronger Java background, it's interesting to see how inheritance/polymorphism is used to work with C#'s stricter and more tangible generics implementation. For example in Java, the OP probably would've fallen back on wildcards for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to declare a type parameter `T` for your `ICriteria` interface in order to use it in its body:

```
public interface ICriteria<T>
{
   string Text { get; set; }
   IList<IParameter<T>> Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

I think this is what your intention is; please let me know if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I did not want to define like this ICriteria<T>

Comment: @Amzath - Then there's no way to use `T` in the interface body - how should the compiler know what it means?

Comment: I am not sure this correct place to ask. How would I add list of parameters of different types into this interface?

Comment: @Amzath: You wouldn't, because such an operation doesn't make sense when there's a type parameter. It would really help if you'd clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add constraint for your generic type:

```
   public interface ICriteria<T,S>
        where T : IParameter<S>
    {
        string Text { get; set; }
        IList<T> Parameters { get; set; }
    }
```